# Spark scala aggregate to an array and concat it

Tags: scala, apache-spark, aggregate-functions

I have a Dataset with a number of columns that looks like this:(Columns -name, timestamp, platform, clickcount, id)

```
Joy  2021-10-10T10:27:16  apple      5   1
May  2020-12-12T22:28:08  android    6   2
June 2021-09-15T20:20:06  Microsoft  9   3
Joy  2021-09-09T09:30:09  android    10  1
May  2021-08-08T05:05:05  apple      8   2
```

I want to group by id and after it should look like

```
Joy  2021-10-10T10:27:16,2021-09-09T09:30:09   apple,android         5,10   1
May  2020-12-12T22:28:08,2021-08-08T05:05:05   android,apple         6,8    2
June 2021-09-15T20:20:06                       Microsoft             9      3
```

After calling for another Api which converts the id to pseudo id I want to map that id and make it to look like

```
Joy  2021-10-10T10:27:16,2021-09-09T09:30:09   apple,android         5,10   1   A12
May  2020-12-12T22:28:08,2021-08-08T05:05:05   android,apple         6,8    2   B23
June 2021-09-15T20:20:06                       Microsoft             9      3   C34
```

I have tried using `groupBy` and `forEach` but I am stuck and unable to proceed further

Answer (score 1):

In order to apply the aggregation you want, you should use `collect_set` as the aggregation function and `concat_ws` in order to join with comma the created arrays:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{collect_set, concat_ws}
import spark.implicits._

val df: DataFrame = Seq(
  ("joy", "2021-10-10T10:27:16", "apple", 5, 1),
  ("may", "2020-12-12T22:28:08", "android", 6, 2),
  ("june", "2021-09-15T20:20:06", "microsoft", 9, 3),
  ("joy", "2021-09-09T09:30:09", "android", 10, 1),
  ("may", "2021-08-08T05:05:05", "apple", 8, 2)
).toDF("name", "timestamp", "platform", "clickcount", "id")

df
  .groupBy("id")
  .agg(
    concat_ws(",", collect_set("timestamp")).as("timestamp"),
    concat_ws(",", collect_set("name")).as("name"),
    concat_ws(",", collect_set("platform")).as("platform"),
    concat_ws(",", collect_set("clickcount")).as("clickcount")
  ).show()
```

The output should be:

```
+---+--------------------+----+-------------+----------+
| id|           timestamp|name|     platform|clickcount|
+---+--------------------+----+-------------+----------+
|  1|2021-10-10T10:27:...| joy|apple,android|      5,10|
|  3| 2021-09-15T20:20:06|june|    microsoft|         9|
|  2|2021-08-08T05:05:...| may|apple,android|       6,8|
+---+--------------------+----+-------------+----------+
```

In order to add a pseudo id column, you should join the created `df` with another dataframe that contains the conversion values or write an UDF that will receive an id value and will convert it into pseudo id.